# Why ruby's version of `tap` is faster than the one implemented in C?

Tags: c, ruby

Please take a look at this pr https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/3281

Rewriting the C version to simple ruby:

```rb
  def tap
    yield(self)
    self
  end
```

made it work faster.

The popular opinion is code written in  C is always faster. This method is very simple in both versions, so why is that? What are the mechanisms at work here?

I'm reasing about Ruby's JIT and AFAIU it includes a few extra steps more than the C code would:
[image]
Namely Tokenization and Parsing. Where is this magic coming from?

Comment: Equivalent code should be faster in a compiled language than in an interpreted one. But who says that we're actually dealing with equivalent code here? The C version calls `rb_yield()`, but how is that implemented? If the called function is actually implemented in Ruby, then it wouldn't be too surprising that the pure Ruby version is faster. If you want to compare apples to apples, write two equivalent applications: one which is **pure** C and one which is **pure** Ruby, and then compare those.

Comment: @FelixG I never claimed that it's equivalent code. Your point is very interesting, but wouldn't `yield` call `rb_yield` anyway under the hood? This is an area of expertise far from mine, hence the question.

Comment: Well, that's the big question i guess... does `yield` call `rb_yield`, or is it the other way around?

Comment: Yeah, that would be a part of the answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kernel.rb` isn’t a “normal” Ruby file. This is a new feature in the Ruby implementation that allows the devs to write certain parts in Ruby.

The [issue introducing it](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16254) gives more details about the reasons for this feature, but one of them is performance: “There are several features which are slower in C than written in Ruby”. The examples there are exception handling and keyword arguments, but it seems that `tap` is also faster in C (possibly due to handling blocks in Ruby versus C).

Part of what this feature does is to compile the Ruby code to bytecode at build time and include it in the resulting binary. This means the first three stages in your diagram (tokenize, parse and compile) only happen once when Ruby is built. Running Ruby only involves evaluating the precompiled bytecode.

You might also want to look at the [commit where this was added](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/46acd0075d80c2f886498f089fde1e9d795d50c4).

Comment: I realise this doesn’t exactly explain _why_ doing this is Ruby is faster than C (I don’t know enough about the details) but it is at least part of the full answer. Perhaps someone else will fill in the missing part in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: this is opinion based... a half informed conjuncture.

It's interesting to note that  when the logic is in a single language (either Ruby or C), then some compile time (or JIT) optimizations become available, while bridging the two languages makes theses optimizations impossible.

For example, the Ruby `.tap` method creates a block and passes an object to that block using `yield`. But if we know the whole logic (during JIT), we could optimize out the extra function calls and perhaps optimize away the creation of a `block` object...

...however, if two different compilers need to compile the code at different times (compiling the `tap` function when Ruby is compiled and compiling the `block` with the JIT), then these optimizations become impossible.